# Como devo passa um array como argumento em PHP e receber todos os dados no shell?

Tags: php, shell-script, shell, sh

Exemplo:

```
 <?php
            $param=array(valor, valor2, valor3);
            $return = shell_exec("sh teste.sh $param");
            echo "<pre>$return</pre>";
  ?>
```

Shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
param=$1
echo $param
```

Dessa maneira só me retorna a palavra `array`, tentei receber como array mas não deu certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta você passar os elementos do array separados por espaço:

```
$return = shell_exec("sh teste.sh ". implode(' ', $param));
```

E no shell script esses valores estarão na variável especial `$@`, que pode ser percorrida com um `for`:

```
for arg in $@
do
    echo $arg
done
```

Isso imprime cada elemento em uma linha. Mas se quiser tudo na mesma linha:

```
echo "$@"
```

---

Se quiser guardar o conteúdo de `$@` em uma variável, fica um pouco mais "chatinho":

```
param=("$@")

# tudo na mesma linha
echo "${param[*]}"

# ou um por linha
for arg in ${param[@]}
do
    echo $arg
done
```

Comment: deu certinho!!!

Comment: o trecho de guarda o conteudo não funcionou, tem outra forma de guarda em uma variavel?

Comment: @RobertSousa Pra guardar tudo em uma só variável só conheço esse jeito

Comment: resolvir assim: COUNT=$(echo $@ | awk '{print $1;}')
separando os valores e contando no for

Comment: mas alem do array, eu queria passar mais duas variaveis e o array, porem ele bagunça quando recebo no shell_script, $1 e $2 $@ dessa maneira, porem na $1 e $2 vem o array tambem!!

Comment: @RobertSousa O shell script recebe todos  os argumentos de uma vez e ele não tem como saber o que era um array antes e o que não era (pro script é tudo uma grande lista de parâmetros), já que o PHP é que sabia disso. Se quer separar argumentos específicos em variáveis próprias, terá que fazer manualmente - pesquise sobre `shift`, talvez seja o que vc precisa

Comment: Sugiro também pesquisar aqui no site, e se não tiver algo assim, aí é o caso de [fazer outra pergunta](/questions/ask) :-)